# Cost of Programmatic Access to MQL in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, programmatically-created, google-cloud-monitoring

I would like to create MQL queries through Cloud Monitoring API in Google Cloud and analyze let's say 1Million datapoints per month. I can not find any data on how much this will cost me except the $0.01 per 1,000 API calls. What is the way to calculate how many API's I will need to analyze this 1M datapoints? Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question that should be asked with Google Cloud support.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the API you'll be using is here:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query

There's a `pageSize` parameter that governs how many `TimeSeriesData` objects to return.  The API can take a long time or time out if you request too many in a single call, so the actual number of calls needed to retrieve a given number of data points can vary.

My suggestion would be to do some testing to see how many data points a single API call will return within an acceptable amount of time and use that to determine how many total calls you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing your analysis in an MQL query if possible. The evaluation will be efficient, and you will bypass this issue altogether.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).